# Classification of involutions on $G_{2}$-homogeneous spaces

Tags: reference-request, lie-groups, lie-algebras, manifolds

Are  you aware  of  a systematic  classification of  involutions  on $G_{2}$-homogeneous spaces?

Comment: No; but what do you mean by a $G_2$-homogeneous space?  Is your $G_2$ an algebraic group, and if yes, then over what field? If the field is $\mathbb R$, then is your $G_2$ compact or not?